# a python script to query MIT START website from local machine

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and the project I've currently set myself includes sending a question from my laptop connected to the net, connect to the [MIT START NLP database](http://start.csail.mit.edu/), enter the question, retrieve the response and display the response.  I've read through the "HOWTO Fetch Internet Resources Using urllib2" at docs.python.org but I seem to be missing some poignant bit of this idea. Here's my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

question = raw_input("What is your question? ")

url = 'http://start.csail.mit.edu/'
values = question

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print the_page
```

and here's the error I'm getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "mitstart.py", line 9, in
>   
>       data = urllib.urlencode(values)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1298, in urlencode
>       raise TypeError TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object

So I'm thinking that the way I set question in vales was wrong, so I did

`values = {question}`

and `values = (question)`

and `values = ('question')`

with no joy.

(I know, and my response is "I'm learning, it's late, and suddenly my wife decided she needed to talk to me about something trivial while I was trying to figure this out)

Can I get some guidance or at least get pointed in the right direction?

Comment: BTW, nicely asked question - clear problem description, great description of what you tried, and you provided the specific error as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) doesn't accept a string as an argument.

As @ernie said you should specify `query` parameter. Also the url is missing the `/startfarm.cgi` part:

```html
<form method="post" action="startfarm.cgi">
```

Updated example:

```py
import cgi
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import urlopen

data = urlencode(dict(query=raw_input("What is your question?"))).encode('ascii')
response = urlopen("http://start.csail.mit.edu/startfarm.cgi", data)

# extract encoding from Content-Type and print the response
_, params = cgi.parse_header(response.headers.get('Content-Type', ''))
print response.read().decode(params['charset'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that your error says: `TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object`

So, while you've created `values` as a string, you need a non-string sequence or a mapping object.

urlencoding requires key value pairs (e.g. a mapping object or a dict), so you generally pass it a dictionary.

Looking at the source for the form, you'll see:

```
<input type="text" name="query" size="60">
```

This means you should create a dict, something like:

```
values = { 'query': 'What is your question?' }
```

Then you should be able to pass that as the argument to urlencode().