# a python script to query a website from local machine

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and i tried implementing [a python script to query MIT START website from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770636/a-python-script-to-query-mit-start-website-from-local-machine/17844004?noredirect=1#comment26048315_17844004) 
concept in Python3.3

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://start.csail.mit.edu/'
values = { 'query': 'What is the capital of China?' }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
binary_data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, binary_data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

print (the_page)
```

the resulting print here just gives me the HTML code for "http://start.csail.mit.edu/" and not the resulting answer page. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `http://start.csail.mit.edu/answer.php?query=[...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form on that page sends a GET request to `http://start.csail.mit.edu/answer.php`, not to `http://start.csail.mit.edu/`.

A GET request appends url-encoded query parameters to the URL with a `?`:

```
url = 'http://start.csail.mit.edu/answer.php'
values = { 'query': 'What is the capital of China?' }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
url = '?'.join([url, data])
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: thanks, that worked like a charm
just out of curiosity though, how would I approach it if the form was doing POST instead of GET

Comment: The way you originally did that; by creating a `Request` object with the data separate from the URL.

Comment: I can recommend you look into the [`requests` library](http://python-requests.org) though; it is a much cleaner and easier to use API for accessing web resources.